# How to manage frontend and backend integration in Continuous Integration Process

Tags: continuous-integration, integration, frontend, backend

**Current Situation:**

Our applications are in Asp.Net using Webforms or MVC and we have frontend and backend teams. Frontend team works on html, css and js(AngularJs), backend team integrated the output of frontend team with the asp.net applications.

Code are separated into frontend and backend repositories and each team works independently(just for scope of work, not without communication).

We have CI setup for backend application which has the normal stuff: pull from git, build, compile and package, then deploy.

For frontend solution, grunt(or gulp) are being used, so there's also compiling and building of css and html codes.

Current process is that frontend team complies the code in their local machines and send to backend team to override js, css and html in the asp.net solution, then check into backend git, then goes into CI process.

**The problem** is in this case there's no way to tell which version of the frontend code we have in backend git repository and since frontend code are built on developers' local machines, with the nature of frontend package management(dynamic versions), the output varies when different developer compiles the code. Hard to tell the changes when checked into GIT.

**What we want to do** now is to move the part that build/compile frontend code into CI process as well and the output should be versioned, then integrate to backend solution for CI process, so we always know exactly what version of frontend code we have in backend and what git commit it's from.

However since we want a particular backend deployed version can match a git commit, if frontend package is generated in a different CI process and only pushed as part of the backend deployment, the frontend changes are not reflected in backend git repository.

Also it will cause problems for backend local development since the process in CI has to be duplicated in local.

**My questions is** that how is this normally being handled so there is a smooth expirence for frontend and backend developers and also easier for testers to know what version of frontend and backend code are deployed?

Comment: Reading your question and thinking if you are a co-worker of mine. Where I work, we have exactly the same situation. Did you solved by yourself the problem?